# Importing contacts to Salesforce - which account type should I use?

Tags: account, record-type, person-accounts

I understand that contacts need to be tied to accounts in Salesforce as without account association, these contacts will be set as 'private' and are essentially orphaned within the organisation.

I have an entirely B2C dataset to load in - should I be using Person Accounts? As an example that fits my use case, say I have a magazine product and I have contacts who subscribe to the digital edition, some who subscribe to the print edition and a third list of newsletter subscribers who do not pay. These are distinct groups when I load them in, but it's possible for a contact to move between the three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally support and believe in using person accounts when many B2C customers are encountered. This wasn't always the case and some older packages may still have issues but I think most do not. Lightning Experience also has some better tools for layouts that reflect the different between a person account and business account. Before activating person acccount, do make sure that you've explored them in a scratch org or sandbox. Also, see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_person_behavior.htm for some consideration when using them.

tldr: Person Accounts are designed for B2C but have some gotcha that must be checked.

Comment: They're certainly a lot better than they were years ago. I wrote [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/117774/2984) years ago, and they were a dismal feature. Salesforce has come a long ways since then, and I would also generally recommend PA for B2C, except for specific circumstances (as the limitations docs list).